# replace values of mutiple columns with NA if another column is NA

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a much larger table than this example with many more clinical variables - a,b,c in the example below which are either present 1 or absent 0. This would be table X below.

I have a column which sums these (rsum below) BUT if there is an NA I can infer that the values in a,b,c should also be missing NA and not absent 0. So the desired answer is table Y below.

```
    X = tibble(a = c(0, 0, 0, 0), b = c(0, 1, 0, 1), c = c(0, 1, 0, 0), 
    rsum = c(0, 2, NA, 1))
    X
    # A tibble: 4 × 4
          a     b     c  rsum
      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
    1     0     0     0     0
    2     0     1     1     2
    3     0     0     0    NA
    4     0     1     0     1

    Y = tibble(a = c(0, 0, NA, 0), b = c(0, 1, NA, 1), c = c(0, 1, NA, 0), 
    rsum = c(0, 2, NA, 1))
    Y
    # A tibble: 4 × 4
          a     b     c  rsum
      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
    1     0     0     0     0
    2     0     1     1     2
    3     NA    NA    NA    NA
    4     0     1     0     1
```

I thought this would be simple enough using variants of `mutate_at` or `mutate` and `across`. But I keep running into bugs and messages about previous solutions being deprecated. My best guess at how this should work was:

```
    mutate(X, across(a:c), ~if_else(is.na(rsum), NA, .)

    Error in `mutate()`:
    ℹ In argument: `~if_else(is.na(rsum), NA, .x)`.
    Caused by error:
    ! `~if_else(is.na(rsum), NA, .x)` must be a vector, not a
      <formula> object.
    Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Is there a simple dplyr solution?

Comment: `X %>% mutate(across(a:c, ~ if_else(is.na(rsum), NA, .x)))`, you need to use `.x` instead of `.`

Comment: Thanks your suggestion works but it's not . or .x. Either of those work. It's that I have used across differently. Your lambda function is within across - and mine wrongly is within the mutate.

Comment: I did not catch that - the function (i.e if_else) has to be within the `across()` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

X = tibble(a = c(0, 0, 0, 0), b = c(0, 1, 0, 1), c = c(0, 1, 0, 0), 
           rsum = c(0, 2, NA, 1))

X %>% 
  mutate(across(a:c, ~ if_else(is.na(rsum), NA, .x)))

# A tibble: 4 × 4
      a     b     c  rsum
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     0     0     0     0
2     0     1     1     2
3    NA    NA    NA    NA
4     0     1     0     1
```